# Automatic CRUD forms generation for .net Windows Forms Applications

Tags: forms, nhibernate, orm, crud

My question is about nHibernate, or any other ORM for .net that can do what I am looking for : for my web developements, I use Django Framework; the admin pages are automatically generated, so that you can do the CRUD operations through a GUI -- web interface -- right after having created your model.

I wonder if nHibernate (or any other ORM/framework) offers the same feature : generating very basic forms for the Create/Update/Delete operations on the tables of the model.

***Note*** : the scope of my question is not ASP.net, but Windows Forms Applications using nHibernate or any ORM.

Comment: NHibernate has nothing to do with presentation but if you change the topic for example to "Generate CRUD from entities in asp.net mvc" the question will be more relevant.

Sharp Architecture is using T4 Toolbox to generate CRUD:
http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/VSTemplatesAndCodeGen.ashx

Comment: Are you looking for something that generates from the NH mappings, or from the class model?

Comment: I am looking for anything that can simply Add records to the data, update them and delete them according to the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Go with [Rocket Framework](http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/) for windows form, though it does not generate forms automatically it has much more flexibility than auto-genearted code set..

- It is developed using .Net 4.0
- It is free
- It not just support doing CRUD directly on tables but combining tables to create your business objects

Check it and see.. I think you gonna like it once you train to use it..

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of scaffolding tools for asp.net mvc but I don't think none of them can be compared with Grails scaffolding capabilities: http://www.grails.org/Scaffolding

http://sharparchitecture.net/
http://www.twinforms.com/products/mvcscaffold/index.php
http://mvccrud.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) has this feature for web apps, but I don't believe it has this feature for WinForms apps.

Subsonic is open source and based on T4 templates, so it's very possible that you could modify the Subsonic T4 templates that generate the WebForms scaffolding and have them generate WinForms scaffolding instead.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago I created a ['Simple reflection form'](http://blog.denouter.net/2008/08/simple-reflection-form.html) : http://blog.denouter.net/2008/08/simple-reflection-form.html 
Perhaps you can make it more suitable by reading the NHibernate mappings and then create the custom form.